# R function/package for clustering using nearest neighbors from given coordinates?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have two (x,y) coordinates that I want to use to cluster my (x,y) data. I want the data to be clustered by the shortest euclidean distance to those given coordinates. Is there an R function/package that allows me to provide these coordinates and then performs the clustering?

Note: I've been using the package "spatstat" for my nearest neighbor calculations.

Comment: Do you want to _start_ from those centers and then adjust te centers based on the new data? Or only use those centers - no changes?

Comment: @G5W Only use those centers, no changes.